# Mongoose: Populate Vehicle array on Users

Tags: javascript, json, mongoose

Ok there is something basic i am not understanding here.
I want to be able to grab the max range from the vehicle model, but i cant seem to get populate to work...if i type owner.vehicles[0].make or anything else it comes up undefined. here's my code.  And to be clear, YES the user IS getting additional vehicle ids, but i cant access any of the vehicle's information so its useless

```
  let owner = await User.findOne({_id: req.user._id});
        console.log(owner);
        owner.vehicles.push(newVehicle);
        owner = await owner.save();

         owner = await User.findOne({ _id: req.user._id }).populate('vehicles');
         owner = await owner.save();
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Document.prototype.populate()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-populate) you either have to pass a callback as a second argument to `populate()` or call `execPopulate()`:

```
 owner = await User.findOne({ _id: req.user._id }).populate('vehicles').execPopulate();
```